# for to call a function from another file in the parent directory in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, file, module

I've searched several threads and found no good solution that explains the use of modules/packages and importing functions from another file.

Suppose, I have got a directory structure like the below:

```
dir_1
 - main2.py
main.py
```

main.py

```
def print_hello():
    return "hello world!!"
```

Now, how can I use this function `print_hello()` in `main2.py` which is inside `dir_1`?
And how can I use this if I've got a highly nested file structure?

Any help is much appreciated!!..

Comment: Try adding an ```__init__.py``` file in ```dir_1```. Adding that makes python consider it as a module

Comment: Btw, the init file is now unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is adding path of the main.py

dir_1/main2.py

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("path/to/the/main")

from main import print_hello

#...
```

But I feel importing parent files is not best practice.